# passing filename with spaces to a shell script

Tags: filenames

The shellscript is very simple:

```
retroarch $* -c /tmp/retroarch/Data/retroarch/gambatte.cfg
```

("retroarch" is another shellscript)

If the filename passed contains spaces it fails:

```
RetroArch [ERROR] :: Could not read ROM file.
```

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use quotes.

Instead of

```
yourcommand some file.name
```

use

```
yourcommand "some file.name"
```

When using variables, quote them as well.

```
yourcommand "$filename"
yourcommand "$@"
...
```

Comment: already tried that but did not work!

Comment: Can you please share the internals of your script? You need to take care internally to maintain double quotes throughout given this variable has spaces in it.

Comment: oh right, the "retroarch" script was missing double quotes...

Answer (score -1):

In general you have to either escape the spaces with backslashes () or wrap the path in either single quotes (') or double quotes (").

```
$ retroarch "$*" -c /tmp/retroarch/Data/retroarch/gambatte.cfg
```

Comment: already tried that, but i always get the error "Could not read ROM file."

Comment: Shouldn't that `"$*"` be `"$@"`?

Comment: @roaima - I kept the example as the OP showed it since my suggestion was around the need to quote it.